# Login System in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to Kivy, and I want to create a simple login system for desktop app.

Here's my python code:

```
class LoginPage(Screen):
    pass
class UserPage(Screen):
    pass
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv_file = Builder.load_file('login.kv')
class LoginApp(App):
    def builder(self):
        return kv_file

LoginApp().run()
```

and kivy file

```
ScreenManagement:
    LoginPage:
    UserPage:
<LoginPage>:
    name: "login_page"
    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: login
        TextInput:
            id: passw
        Button:
            text: "go"
            on_release: app.root.current = "user"
<UserPage>:
    name: "user"
    Button:
        text: "back"
        on_release: app.root.current = "login_page"
```

I want it to change the screen only if text in form is what I need (e.g - TextInput(login) = 'username', TextInput(pass) = 'password').

I know I need to write a method for this, but I need help with this.

Comment: `screen_manager.switch_to(Screen())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must create a method that I get the texts and do the verification. This method should be called when the button is pressed. If the credentials are correct you must change the Screen.

***.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

class LoginPage(Screen):
    def verify_credentials(self):
        if self.ids["login"].text == "username" and self.ids["passw"].text == "password":
            self.manager.current = "user"

class UserPage(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv_file = Builder.load_file('login.kv')

class LoginApp(App):
    def builder(self):
        return kv_file

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LoginApp().run()
```

***.kv**

```
ScreenManagement:
    LoginPage:
    UserPage:

<LoginPage>:
    name: "login_page"
    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: login
        TextInput:
            id: passw
            password: True # hide password
        Button:
            text: "go"
            on_release: root.verify_credentials()

<UserPage>:
    name: "user"
    Button:
        text: "back"
        on_release: app.root.current = "login_page"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your .py code under LoginPage you can initialize class attributes such as username and password. You can create these class attributes to use in other methods in the class. They can store a username and password. For example:

```
class LoginPage(Screen):

      def __init__(self, username, password):
             self.username = username
             self.password = password

      def check_password(self):
             self.username = 'random_username'
             self.password = 'random_password'
             if self.ids.login.text == str(self.username) and self.ids.passw.text == str(self.password)
                          self.parent.current = 'user'
```

First you created the LoginPage class, and passed the kivy screen class as the argument.

Secondly we initialized two class attributes: username and password. We gave self.username, and self.password the values username and password which match the parameters username and password.

Third we created a function called check_password, and passed self so that it can gain the class attributes (username and password) that we defined in the initialize method. We can give those attributes values, so I gave the self.username the value 'random_username', and self.password the value 'random_password'.

Fourth we can run an if statement, and the username entered matches the value that we have for self.username, and the password entered in the textinput box matches what we have for self.password, the current page can immediately flip to your user page (self.parent.current = 'user').

In your .kv file you'll need to "bind" the function that we created with a button, so that when the Button is released, this function will be initiated. 
In the .kv file you can change the "go" button to something such as:

```
  Button:
      text:'GO'
      on_release: root.check_password()
```

When your button is released it will initiate the check_password function that we just created that checks if the username and password entered in the TextInput boxes are valid.